# Custom mapping Spring MVC, Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

My project using Spring MVC and Spring Data MongoDB to connect mongoDB database
This is my example code:

```
public class Data extends BasicDBObject{

    @Id
    public String id;
    @Transient
    public String obName;

    public String getId() {
       return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
    }
    public String getObName() {
       return obName;
    }
    public void setObName(String obName) {
       this.obName = obName;
    }
}
```

**Custom converter**

```
@ReadingConverter
public class DataReadConverter implements Converter<BasicDBObject, Data>{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter#convert(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public Data convert(BasicDBObject source) {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setId((ObjectId) source.get("_id"));
        data.putAll(source.toMap());
        return data;
    }


}
```

**Register converter**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!--    MongoDB Config -->
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="opmdrive" mongo-ref="mongo"/>


<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="com.chick.opm.model.object">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.chick.opm.spring.DataReadConverter"/>
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.chick.opm.spring.DataWriteConverter"/>
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>

<bean id="mongoOperation" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.LoggingEventListener"/>
```

**get data and mapping**

```
List<Data> updatedUser = getCurrentMongoOperations().findAll(Data.class, "accounts");
System.out.println(updatedUser.get(0).getId().toStringMongod());
return updatedUser;
```

**Actual result**
Error cannot cast BasicDBObject to Data

**Expect result**

```
[
  {
    "id": "5820428b1a82a72dfce0c914",
    "username": 17671794,
    "password": "mypassword"
  },
  {
    "id": "5820428d1a82a72dfce0c915",
    "username": 81964940,
    "password": "mypassword"
  },
  {
    "id": "5822a7e642af5424d0bb07ab",
    "username": 75165254,
    "password": "mypassword"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace for the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution is .toMap() function before response a hashMap like this:

```
Map map = ((HashMap) collectionService.getById(id, dataName)).toMap()
return map;
```